# Where are there good Xj3D in Eclipse Tutorials?

Tags: java, eclipse, 3d, java-3d

This may seem a dumb question but does anyone know where there are "good" tutorials for setting up and using Xj3D with Eclipse?  I have been to www.xj3d.org but there is so little there and what is there I can't get to work and actually display anything.  I know I am doing something or everything wrong and my company would really prefer if I use this (why?  I don't know since I am the only one using it in the whole company but it is what it is).

Thanks in Advance,
JH

Answer (score 0):

This is how i setup Xj3D in Eclipse:

1. Download the .zip file from here:

   - http://www.java.net/node/706300
2. extract the .jar file to a folder
3. open Eclipse
4. Open Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> User Librarys
5. Click new and name it "X3DModelLoader"
6. Click on "X3DModelLoader"
7. Click on Add JARs...
8. Find the jar file you just downloaded to a folder

Then you should be all setup, all you need to do is make sure the library is in the build path for your project and then you are all set!

Here is some code to get you started:

```
package com;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.media.j3d.Alpha;
import javax.media.j3d.Appearance;
import javax.media.j3d.Background;
import javax.media.j3d.BoundingSphere;
import javax.media.j3d.BranchGroup;
import javax.media.j3d.Canvas3D;
import javax.media.j3d.DirectionalLight;
import javax.media.j3d.RotationInterpolator;
import javax.media.j3d.Shape3D;
import javax.media.j3d.Transform3D;
import javax.media.j3d.TransformGroup;
import javax.media.j3d.ViewPlatform;
import javax.vecmath.Color3f;
import javax.vecmath.Point3d;
import javax.vecmath.Vector3d;
import javax.vecmath.Vector3f;

import com.interactivemesh.j3d.interchange.ext3d.XModelLoader;
import com.microcrowd.loader.java3d.max3ds.Loader3DS;
import com.sun.j3d.loaders.Scene;
import com.sun.j3d.loaders.objectfile.ObjectFile;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.applet.MainFrame;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.ColorCube;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.ViewingPlatform;

public class ModelLoaderExample extends Applet
{
    public ModelLoaderExample()
    {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        GraphicsConfiguration config = SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration();
        Canvas3D canvas = new Canvas3D(config);
        add("Center", canvas);

        BranchGroup content = getScene();
        content.compile();

        SimpleUniverse universe = new SimpleUniverse(canvas);
        universe.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();
        universe.addBranchGraph(content);
    }

    public BranchGroup getScene()
    {
        BranchGroup group = new BranchGroup();

        XModelLoader loader = new XModelLoader();
        loader.setFlags(ObjectFile.LOAD_ALL);
        loader.setBasePath("/my/base/path");

        Scene scene = null;

        try
        {
            scene = loader.load("/my/base/path/myObject.x3d");

        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

        group.addChild(scene.getSceneGroup());

        Background background = new Background(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        background.setApplicationBounds(new BoundingSphere());
        group.addChild(background);

        return group;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Frame frame = new MainFrame(new ModelLoaderExample(), 256, 256);
    }
}
```